# Can you get a Storage Account URI via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, uri

I am very new to Azure and am working with powershell to automate some stuff. I am hoping to use the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` cmdlet, which requires the URI. I was wondering how I can get a storage account URI? Can I use a Powershell command to grab it?

I tried running the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` cmdlet, but it does not return the URI. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
$Account = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name <account-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>
$Account.PrimaryEndpoints #Gives you all endpoints
$Account.PrimaryEndpints.Blob #Gives you blob endpoint
```

The output of [`Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/get-azurermstorageaccount?view=azurermps-6.13.0) is of kind [`PSStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.management.storage.models.psstorageaccount) so you can see other properties available to you.

Answer (score 1):

The `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` requires not only an uri to your storage account, but to a blob container on your storage account.

The uri can be taken from the properties of the `AzureStorageContainer` object:

```bsh
Get-AzStorageAccount -StorageAccountName <name of your storage account> -ResourceGroupName <name of rg that holds your storage account> | 
  Get-AzStorageContainer | 
  Select-Object Name,@{n='Uri'; e={$_.CloudBlobContainer.Uri}}
```

If there is no blob container in your storage account yet, you can create one using `New-AzStorageContainer`.